# Deduction of $\vdash[(\exists x) B \Rightarrow (\forall x) C] \Rightarrow (\forall x) (B\Rightarrow C) $

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

Prove the following:

$\vdash[(\exists x) B \Rightarrow (\forall x) C] \Rightarrow (\forall x) (B\Rightarrow C)
$

I came up with the following:

1. $(\exists x) B \Rightarrow (\forall x) C$     $\quad \quad  $    (Hypothese)
2. $(\forall x )C \Rightarrow C \quad \quad \quad \quad $ (Rule A4)
3. $ (\exists x) B \Rightarrow C \quad \quad \quad \quad $ (MP 1,2)
4. $ \neg C \Rightarrow (\forall x) \neg B  $  $ \quad \quad  $  (Contraposition)
5. $\neg C \Rightarrow \neg B $ $ \quad \quad \quad \quad $  (Rule A4)
6. $B \Rightarrow C \quad \quad \quad  \quad  \quad $(Contraposition)
7. $(\forall x) (B \Rightarrow C)\quad \quad \quad \quad $    (Gen)
8. $[(\exists x) B \Rightarrow (\forall x) C] \vdash (\forall x) (B \Rightarrow C)$  (1-7)
9. $\vdash[(\exists x) B \Rightarrow (\forall x) C] \vdash (\forall x) (B \Rightarrow C)$
   (Corollary 2.6 of the book introduction to Mathematical Logic)

Is this correct?

Comment: Who are the book's author(s)?